# Buscar email en cadena de texto

Tags: php

estoy buscando por el mundo si se podría buscar una dirección de email en una cadena de texto o string de texto ( no se exactamente que diferencia hay ) y como podría hacer para sacar únicamente esa dirección para usarla como variable.

Había pensado en usar [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php) y derivados pero claro al ser una dirección variable para cada caso no se como podría usarlo, ya que parece que tengo que poner el texto completo.

La idea es sacarlo de un textarea que rellena el usuario.

Me daria igual que se haga en php, o jQuery aunque preferiría poder hacerlo en php.

¿hay alguna forma de hacer esto o tengo que poner un input para poner el mail exclusivo?

Comment: Para poder extraer el email de un string tendría que estar bien bordeado por caracteres únicos y siempre iguales, o bien como dices tener el mismo tamaño, y este último es variable. Lo más aconsejable y sencillo de manejar es que tenga un campo propio.

Comment: Puedes usar [esta sencilla expresión regular](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disculpen mi español, no soy nativo, pero intentaré explicar una solución posible para tu problema.

El problema en este caso es que los usuarios pueden escribir lo que quieran en el `textarea`. Por eso no puedes asegurarte de que tu código encontrará el email. Te aconsejo utilizar un input para cada tipo de data que necesites utilizar directamente en el código.

Si de todas formas quieres encontrar el email, aquí tienes un método para hacerlo en `php` con `preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject, array $matches )`. Es una función que te permite encontrar texto basado en expresiones regulares. Documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php

Aquí el `$pattern` será la expresión regular, en tu caso puedes utilizar `$pattern = '/[a-z\d._%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b/i';`. `$subject` es la variable con el texto que estaba en el `textarea` y `$matches` es la variable que va a contener los correos encontrados en el `$subject`.

### Ejemplo

```
$pattern = '/[a-z\d._%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b/i';
$subject = "Hola, me llamo Juan y mi correo electrónico es juan@tenorio.es. Saludos!";
preg_match ( $pattern, $subject, $matches );

print_r($matches);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => juan@tenorio.es
)
*/
```

### Más información

- Una pregunta parecida en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050915/getting-emails-out-of-string-regex-syntax-preg-match-all
- Expresiones regulares: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tu español es mejor que el de muchos nativos. He tenido que corregir muy pocas cosas. Si no hubieras dicho que tu idioma nativo no es el español, nunca lo habría sospechado. Un saludo ;)

Comment: Funciona perfectamente :) muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda... lo he pasado a una función para poder usarlo en distintas partes del código y estoy encantado. Coincido con @ElChiniNet en que tu español es mejor que el de muchos nativos.

Comment: Este código solo funciona para cuando detecta la primer estructura de correo, si hay más por delante no las muestra.

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta y como seria en caso que la primera estructura no sea correo?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrar mails es complicado, pero la régex definida en el RFC5322 es lo más preciso que puedes usar sin utilizar frameworks.

```
$pattern = '/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/iD'
```

una vez obtenido el pattern puedes encontrar los grupos con:

```
preg_match_all($pattern,$string_a_buscar,$array_matches)
```