# Obtener email de un campo varchar(en la BD) y luego actualizar

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo los siguientes datos grabados en mi columna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver, es un **varchar** y uno puedo grabar lo que quiera,
la idea es crear una aplicacion en **php**, que solo me tome dentro del **varchar** el **email**, y luego actualice la tupla...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
        $listaDeCorreos  = mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL, iden FROM planilla", $db);



        $cadenaEntrada = $listaDeCorreos;
        $patron = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i'; 
        preg_match_all($patron, $cadenaEntrada, $matches);
        echo $matches[0][0];
```

Por lo que entiendo, estas lineas toman solo el **email** dentro del **varchar**, 
pero necesito asesoramiento para realizar la parte en donde se rescata el valor tomado en **$matches** y actualizar la tupla con el dato correcto...

**Estructura de la tabla:**

```
 CREATE TABLE planilla (
 EMAIL VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 iden MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 PRIMARY KEY (iden)
 )
```

Comment: Bienvenido Francisco, te recomiendo realizar el [recorrdo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que veas como funciona y se trabaja aquí en el foro. Debes de aprender a como preguntar aquí, ya que no podemos crear todo el codigo por ti. Debemos ver lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: @alanfcm estoy informandome sobre la funcion php que realiza validaciones, de momento nada, me gustaría recibir ayuda y sugerencias debido a que mi conocimiento en php es basico.

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo añade el codigo que llevas hecho, de esa forma te podremos ayudar mejor. Veo también que en la columna email tienes nombres ademas del email. Eso no es nada recomendable, lo mejor es tener una columna para el nombre y otra unicamente para el email. Saludos!

Comment: @JesúsMagallón si tengo claro lo de la normalizan, es como se encuentra actualmente la base, yo no la tengo así! y bueno, a nivel de ayuda, no necesariamente deseo que me desarrollen la aplicación(como indica Brandon Castillo), pero si podrian ayudarme con funciones o picks que podrian ser claves. Gracias de todos modos...

Comment: Puedes usar regex `[a-z\d._%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b`, mira esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/77688/44425

Comment: @Kevin Muchas gracias por la informacion ;)

Comment: @alanfcm ya ingrese parte del codigo

Comment: @JesúsMagallón ya ingrese el código que llevo

Comment: ¿Qué es el campo 'iden' en tu consulta?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob es el id de la tabla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo ya tienes una base de datos con correos los cuales no todos son correos persé, si no que viene con más paja y deseas depurar esa base, de ser así le falta mucha carne a tu código, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo funcionaría tu script. Te dejo comentado el código para que te guíes

```
    <?php
//Primero te debes conectar a tu base de datos con tus credenciales
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'COLLINS');

//Validamos que se haya creado la conexión
if( mysqli_connect_errno() ){
  echo 'Falló la conexión a la base de datos. ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}

else{
  //Preparamos tu query y le ponemos Alias a tus campos
  $query = "SELECT EMAIL AS 'MAIL', iden AS 'ID' FROM planilla";
  $result = mysqli_query( $db, $query );
  //Maneja los errores de consulta o retorno de registros
  if( !$result ){
    echo 'La consulta está mal construida' . '<br>';
  }

  else{
    if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) <= 0){
      echo 'La consulta no retornó información' . '<br>';
    }

    else{
      //Creas la expesión regular
      $regexp = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';

      //Ciclamos los resultados y sacamos los datos
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
        //Suponiendo que el ID es un entero, si no quitale el (int)
        $id = (int) $row['ID'];
        $text = $row['MAIL'];

        preg_match_all( $regexp, $text, $matches );
        //Ahora validamos que existan resultados y coincidencias
        if( !empty( $matches[0][0] ) ){
          //Si no está vacío entonces actualizas con lo que te regresó el regex
          $subquery = "UPDATE planilla SET EMAIL = '".$matches[0][0]."'
          WHERE iden = " . $id;
          mysqli_query( $db, $subquery );

          //Ejecutas la consulta y validas que se haya actualizado
          if( mysqli_affected_rows( $db ) <= 0){
            echo 'No fue posible actualizar el campo con ID ' .  $id . ' el nuevo valor: ' . $matches[0][0] . '<br>';
          }

          else{
            echo 'Se actualizó correctamente el valor: ' . $matches[0][0] . '<br>';
          }
        }

        else{
          //Si está vacío entonces mandar error
          echo 'El mail ' . $text . ' no cumplió con la expresión regular' . '<br>';
        }
      }

      //Liberas memoria (Como buen programador) y cierras conexión
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      mysqli_close($db);
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

**TE DEJO LAS IMAGENES DE CÓMO ESTÁ TRABAJANDO**
[image: Estos son los datos que tu tienes]
[image: Esta es la actualización]
[image: Este es el resultado]

Comment: lo probare de inmediato ;)

Comment: 'La consulta está mal construida'   sera por las comillas en el AS

Comment: le cambie por:

      `$result  = mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL AS 'MAIL', iden AS 'ID' FROM planilla", $db);`

  y me indica que la consulta no arroja información, utilizo php5.3.13

Comment: Entonces no estamos haciendo bien la consulta, postea la estructura de la base.

Comment: listo, edite mi pregunta, la integre al final.

Comment: mmmm acabo de probar mi código con una base de prueba y jala perfecto. Si cambiaste la consulta, te recuerdo que mysqli_query el primer parámetro es la conexión $db, y luego la consulta.

Comment: cambie para probar solamente, pero con tu queri me arroja error, lo adjunto en tu respuesta.

Comment: quieres que lo veamos por teamviewer?

Comment: Ahí lo estoy probando te dejo imagenes. StackOverFlow es un foro de apoyo, conectarnos por TeamViewer lo considero consultoría.

Comment: Estoy seguro que lo que está fallando es la variable $db, puedes poner cómo la estas declarando? Debería tener la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83132/discussion-between-francisco-acevedo-and-alberto-siurob).

Comment: en 20 horas mas, me permite asignar la recompensa extra, no lo olvidare ;)

Answer (score 2):

Para empezar podés leer un poco sobre **expresiones regulares**, [aquí](https://diego.com.es/expresiones-regulares-en-php) tienes un buen tutorial para empezar.

Con respecto a la pregunta en sí, si no está en tu poder reestructurar la base de datos para poder trabajar con campos separados, la única opción que tienes es analizar el texto en busca de un patrón que coincida con un email, y por esto es que te recomiendo una lectura sobre expresiones regulares.

Luego, un poco más orientado en el tema, podés investigar sobre el [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) que sirve para realizar una comparación global de una **expresión regular** en una cadena de texto. Por último, puedes comenzar utilizandolo para matchear correos electrónicos en los valores de tu columna `email`, por ejemplo:

```
<?php 
    $cadenaEntrada = 'maria andrea ma@gmail.com'; //el valor del campo email
    $patron = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i'; //un patrón ejemplo para matchear correos electrónicos
    preg_match_all($patron, $cadenaEntrada, $matches);
    echo $matches[0][0]; // primera coincidencia del patrón en la cadena de entrada.
?>
```

> Ejemplos:

```
$cadenaEntrada = 'maria andrea ma@gmail.com'
echo $matches[0][0]; //ma@gmail.com
---
$cadenaEntrada = 'Josem_ gtgmail.com jgt@gmail.com.ar, thh@live.com';
echo $matches[0][0]; //jgt@gmail.com.ar
echo $matches[0][1]; //thh@live.com
```

Comment: lo pondré en marcha apenas pueda, muchas gracias por la información :) si tengo problemas te aviso

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo, sin embargo en esta comunidad se espera que las publicaciones no solo muestren la duda, si no también lo que han intentado aunque hayan tenido errores; de otro modo es solo darle la respuesta y así no es como funcionamos

Comment: @AlfredoPaz que equivoco estas, debido a que estoy buscando sugerencias y no un todo! se entiende?
ademas que de la misma forma debieran funcionar, debido a que existen preguntas bien valorizadas y tickeadas cuando ni si quiera compilan de forma correcta!!

Comment: @mario-l esta es la parte en donde obtengo el dato, como podría hacer el proceso de actualización?